# Wordpress error warning "Creating default object from empty value in......slideshow_layerslider.php on line 28"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following warning on our Wordpress site: "Warning: "Creating default object from empty value in...../themes/enfold/config-templatebuilder/avia-shortcodes/slideshow_layerslider/slideshow_layerslider.php on line 28"

I've uninstalled all the plugins, reinstalled one by one and this has not resolved the problem.
PHP is up to date.
WordPress version is up to date, as is the theme version.

I'm not sure how to fix this. If there's someone who could help that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: Contact the dev of the theme. https://kriesi.at/support/topic/layer-slider-problem-after-activating-the-enfold-theme/ shows someone with the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the theme which is currently 4.8.3 - https://kriesi.at/documentation/enfold/theme-update/ and that should fix it :)

Comment: Question says he's running latest version of the theme. `wp theme list` says I'm running latest version too but I get the same error.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts I'm with the Enfold team. Updating the theme will fix the issue. Make sure you are using Enfold 5.4. If you added your Personal Token in Enfold theme options and did not receive the update, try using Envato Market plugin: https://www.envato.com/lp/market-plugin/. If it doesn't work, start a thread on our support forum: https://kriesi.at/support/.

Comment: I see - the customer hasn't updated to 5.4. I can ask them to do that but if not will ignore this error.

Comment: Oh, can't update on their behalf:  https://kriesi.at/support/topic/wp-cli-wp-theme-update-enfold-not-working/

Comment: @TommyPeanuts if your customer is not using LayerSlider, you can deactivate or remove it in Enfold theme options > Layout Builder > Integrated (Bundled) LayerSlider Plugin. 

Also, please remove your downvote from my initial answer so it can be helpful to others :)

Comment: OK. My main concern is security, and not having outdated WP sites running. I have disabled the customer's site and told them to contact you for help fixing this.